# Selecting a group from groups based on one row condition

Tags: sql-server, group-by, query

There is a group of rows which have the losscode and service odom. The contractnumber and service odometer are used to group the rows.

Please, may you help me to find the way to select only the row group which have the `slosscode='REVSTD'`?

[image]

Comment: What does grouping mean if you only want one row? The following returns the row: `SELECT sContractNumber, sLossCode, iServiceOdom WHERE sLossCode='REVSTD'`

Comment: @Maricruz If you're going to access the site from different browsers or devices, an unregistered (cookie-based) account isn't going to work for you. Consider [registering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) instead, and then [merging your accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way you'll retain reputation earned, be able to edit your question without peer review, and accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want all rows of the group(s) where at least one row of the group has `sLossCode = 'REVSTD'`. In this case, you don't need `GROUP BY`. You can use either a self join (but that would only work under certain `UNIQUE` constraint requirements) or an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT s.sContractNumber, s.sLossCode, s.iServiceOdom
FROM service_table AS s
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM service_table AS q
        WHERE q.sLossCode = 'REVSTD'
          AND q.sContractNumber = s.sContractNumber
          AND q.iServiceOdom = s.iServiceOdom
      ) ;
```